# Create Canvas radial (not in to out) gradient

Tags: canvas, gradient, radial-gradients

I need to draw a circle with a gradient inside.

`createRadialGradient()` is creating gradient from inside to outside, `createLinearGradient()` is creating gradient from side to side, but I need to create something like on picture below.

Can anyone help me with this?
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a built in function or are you looking for a custom function that will be writing pixels?

Comment: An idea would be to produce a linear gradient 1px high and of equal or greater length than the arc. Then, for each pixel within the desired region, you find the percent of the angle that it is, and then map that to a pixel the same percent of the way through the gradient, and draw the gradient value at that pixel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may fill all pixels of your shape calculating each pixel's color. Or just draw a lot of lines of different colors. I used the second way:

```
function drawAngleGradient(ctx, options){
    var delta = options.endAngle - options.startAngle;
    for(var angle = options.startAngle; angle < options.endAngle; angle += options.angleStep){
        var t = (angle - options.startAngle) / delta;
        drawLine(ctx, {
            start: options.center,
            end: [
                options.center[0] + options.radius * Math.cos(angle),
                options.center[1] + options.radius * Math.sin(angle)
            ],
            color: mixColors(options.startColor, options.endColor, t)
        });
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vgeu3upz/

Comment: Instead of doing the `mixColors` method, you could produce the gradient in a 1xN canvas, where N is equal to the arc length, and then sample from that. It would let you do any linear gradient. I can also vouch for your solution because it produces the same result regardless of which direction the arm sweeps.

Comment: No, you shouldn't do like that. Drawing gradient (as well as getting pixel color) is not a light operation so your code will work a lot slower. It's very easy to improve mixColors to support any stops and it's better way.

Comment: I agree. Supposing that you make a new gradient every time, my suggestion is awful. But a one time instantiation and many uses wouldn't be all that bad